# How to use mpi4py to pass list of lists with unequal length?

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, mpi, mpi4py

Suppose I have an numpy array consists of lists with unequal length (which is very large, so I would like it to be only in rank==0),

```
if rank == 0:
    v0 = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [3, 4], [1, 5, 7, 8]])
```

Suppose I have two cores, I want them to receive:

```
v1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [3, 4]])
V2 = np.array([[2, 3], [1, 5, 7, 8]])
```

How can I achieve this using mpi4py. (If `v0` is in all ranks, we simply need to index
`v1 = v0[np.array([0, 2])]` and `v2 = v0[np.array([1, 3])]`.)

In general, v0 has a very large size, say N * 1000 sublists, where N is the number of ranks. I want the i-th rank to have sublists i, i+N, ...i+999*N.

Comment: I don't think making an array from this list will help you.

Comment: Does numpy even do this? Anyway, make a single array with pointers to the locations where the subarrays start, and use that to `MPI_Scatterv`.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Yes, you need to set the dtype=object. Can you wirte an example about your comments?

Comment: @hpaulj Sorry, I don't understand your point. This array is the big data load from disk, which need to be processed further by other processors. Due to memory limit, I want just one copy of this big data in rank=0. Are there any other more efficient and convient way to do this?

Comment: `alist[::2]` and `alist[1::2]` will split a list into two groups, every other element.

Comment: @hpaulj please read my question carefully